# Is there a canonical question regarding Java's Scanner?

Tags: discussion, canonical

An extremely common error for new Java programmers using the `Scanner` class is to have code like the following:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an integer");
int userInput = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter your name");
String name = scan.nextLine();
```

This fails because they give the `int` input on its own line, so `name` gets assigned `""` (up to the end of the line).

Is there a canonical Q&A for this error, or should I make one?

Comment: Does this fit the bill? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: @BoltClock I believe so

Comment: Yes there is a [quite comprehensive one available.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446599/how-to-use-scanner-to-correctly-read-user-input-from-system-in-and-act-on-it)